# In Xamarin if I merge two resource directories can I still make changes to each and have them appear when the resources are searched for?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is what I mean.  If I have these two resource classes:

```
public class Theme1 : ResourceDictionary
{
    protected Theme1()
    {
        Add(nameof(IconColor), "#111111");
        Add(nameof(PageBackgroundColor), "#111111");
    }
    public Color IconColor { get; }
    public Color PageBackgroundColor { get; 
}

public class Theme2 : ResourceDictionary
{
    protected Theme2()
    {
        Add(nameof(IconColorA), "#222222");
        Add(nameof(PageBackgroundColorA), "#222222");
    }
    public Color IconColorA { get; }
    public Color PageBackgroundColorA { get; }
}
```

If I then merge them like this:

```
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new Theme1());
Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new Theme2());
```

If after merging, I now change the value of one of the keys in Theme1, will that be reflected when there is a search for the resource?

Comment: Not sure if that what you mean, but I think it depends how you are consuming them as a StaticResource or DynamicResource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change MergedDictionaries value, you can assign a value directly.

```
App.Current.Resources["IconColor"] = Color.Blue;
```